# how extract information from script tag

Tags: php, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In my code after few queries I got variable content like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir=ltr>
  <head>
    <script>
      mapslite = {
        START_TIME: new Date()
      };
      mapslite.getBasePageResponse = function(cacheResponse) {
        delete mapslite.getBasePageResponse;
        cacheResponse([[[3988.776886432477,103.7950744,1.3090672],[0,0,0],[1024,768],13.10000038146973],"/maps-lite/js/2/maps_lite_20160404_RC01",107,null,null,["en",""],["/maps/lite/ApplicationService.GetEntityDetails","/maps/lite/ApplicationService.UpdateStarring","/maps/lite/ApplicationService.Search",null,"/maps/lite/suggest","/maps/lite/directions","/maps/lite/MapsLiteService.GetHotelAvailability",null,"https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/.....
,[null,null,1.3090672,103.7950744],null,"11401",null,"PjoDV_jjE8yPuATo_LmYDA","Asia/Singapore",[["\u003cb\u003eBuses\u003c/b\u003e from this station",[[3,"bus.png",null,"Bus",[["https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/b/bus.png",0,[15,15],null,0]]]],[[null,null,null,null,"0x31da18325b415901:0xeb661015c651c24a",[[5,["48",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da19f34e04d59b:0x5758ef6990938b",[[5,["61",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da1a5b8b75c379:0x6a13e189555f9fab",[[5,["95",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da1a16ea23bf95:0xd7c90f15535c2b9f",[[5,["106",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da10a7613d616f:0xf1f61ffeac2ea8a4",[[5,["970",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da1a0bd6262d0b:0xfbd5d2bfd7a1252",[[5,["NR8",1,"#ffffff"]]]]],null,0,"5"]]],["http://www.google.com/search?q=
....
[0,0,"",0,1,null,null,null,0,0,1,1,0,"map,common",null,0,0,1,null,null,1,"1","2,1","","",0],null,null,"PjoDV_jjE8yPuATo_LmYDA",null,null,null,null,"//consent.google.com","2.maps_lite_20160404_RC01"]);
      };
      executeOgJs = function() {

        delete executeOgJs;
      };
    </script>
```

The important information I want to extract is all the numbers at "this station" line:  "48, 61,95,106,970,NR8" (it next to ",1,"#ffffff").

I tried with python code:

```
 tree = html.fromstring(buspage, base_url=detail['result']['url'])
        bus_elm = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tr/td")
```

but got some errors and difficulties. Is there any way to do it conveniently in PHP?

Comment: scraping some ones script, why?

Comment: because there is no api to do this, although it is public info. So here is the only way, and it is not illegal. However I want to come back to coding aspect, how PHP enable this task ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet would be using regex, if you are sure that you always have that specific structure.

An expression matching the 'array' ["5N4", 323, "#asdasd"] is
`(\[\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*?\"\,\d*?\,\".*?\"\])`.

You can use `explode()` in PHP or `split()` in python to get the number you want (in this case 5N4) like this:

```
function get_numbers_from($input) {
    $matches = preg_match_all('(\[\"[]a-zA-Z0-9]*?\"\,\d*?\,\".*?\"\])', $input);
    foreach($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
        array_push($numbers, explode(',', $match)[0]);
    }

    return $numbers;
}
```

Comment: actually that format appear at some other places also. If search for "from this station", then the last occurrence will be the place to extract, you can see from source code here:  view-source:https://www.google.com/maps/place/Blk+12/@1.3090672,103.7928857,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xd6a22994a5bdbbc3

Comment: You can do a preg_match to capture everything from "from this station" to </script> and then try that regex on it.

Comment: there are 4 places with "from this station" I only looking for the last one. And the string regex should process is: [\"91\",1,\"#ffffff\"] get number 91. Can you put that preg_match to the answer as well ?

Comment: I think I know how to get the last part, using:"end(explode('from this station',$str))" but can you update the regex for the right format I mention above?